# How to Display an Error Message with a button

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, vue.js, axios

So I currently have this code that asks the user if they want to delete a record from the database via ReactJS

```
methods: {
    async deleteStatus(id) {
         try {
           if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete?")){
           await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/delete-status/${id}`);
           }
           window.location.reload();
         } catch (err) {
           console.log(err);
         }
      },
  },
```

Now my goal is to create an error message saying "Cannot Delete" If the record cannot be deleted, mainly due to a foreign key constraint in the backend. Is there a window function or a button function that relay that information to the user?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do that by getting the response from your delete API and based on that you can do that in the `try` block.

If there will be any error while deleting the record, API will return some different status code or message based on that you can do this.

```
try {
    if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete?")){
        const res = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/delete-status/${id}`);
        if (res.message === 'Success') { 
           alert('Successfully Deleted');
        } else {
           alert('Cannot Delete');
        }
    }
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are using Javascript in HTML page or a local HTML server.
Then,
In The Catch,
You Have To Write `alert("Cannot Delete");`
This Will Look Like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        try {
            //Your Code Here
        } catch (error) {
            alert("Cannot Delete");
            //OR
            alert(error);
        }
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And Output Will Be:
[image: output Image]
Note:
This Wont Work if you are running javascript separately.

Comment: If It Work Then accept so others will know it is solved and they me get help from this.